# Two dimensional ball motion on a plane

Tags: classical-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics

Suppose i have a horizontal table. Choose a standard cartesian coordinate such that the $x-y$ plane coincise with the table. Assume that the table is not smooth. Suppose i have a solid ball with initial velocity $\vec{v} = (v_x,v_y,0)$ and The ball initially slipping with angular velocity $\dot{\theta} = (\omega,0,0)$.

> How can i determine when the ball is not slip from the Newton's law and the torque equation ? 
>   This seems a bit complicated because now there is two friction force, first because the rotation of the ball and the second because the $x-$axis motion. This question is the extension of my answer in a question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/370128/spin-shot-pool-physics).

Comment: Related : [Rotational physics of a playing card](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/299423)

Comment: The ball will not slip, when the rotation of the ball due to the horizontal velocity equals the angular velocity.